# Openpyxl - Remove duplicates when copy and pasting data between workbooks

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

My script copies from one workbook to another and sorts them based on value. I'm trying to find a way to remove duplicates. I tried to use an `if` statement to check if the data already exists in the destination workbook, but it is not working correctly. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = load_workbook('testData.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('testTemplate.xlsx')

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
mr = ws.max_row

ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
A = ws2.max_row
B = ws2.max_row
C = ws2.max_row

ws2values = set()

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row = 2, min_col = 1, max_row = mr, max_col = 2):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "A":
            if ws2.cell(row = A + 1, column = 1).value in ws2values:
                pass
            else:
                ws2.cell(row = A + 1, column = 1).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
                A += 1

        elif cell.value == "B":
            if ws2.cell(row = B + 1, column = 1).value in ws2values:
                pass
            else:
                ws2.cell(row = B + 1, column = 1).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
                B += 1

        elif cell.value == "C":
            if ws2.cell(row = C + 1, column = 1).value in ws2values:
                pass
            else:
                ws2.cell(row = C + 1, column = 1).value = (cell.offset(column = + 1).value)
                C += 1

wb2.save('testTemplate.xlsx')
```

Comment: you are checking for items in the set `ws2values` but it is always empty? In your else statements add those values into the set?

Comment: It looks like your logic is a little faulty and thus your checks will never succeed. You might do better using three lists (one each for A,B and C) to remove duplicates and then `zip()` across these for the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the `pandas` tag in your question but in case you're interested, you can use some of this library functions to avoid loops, speed up your transformation and get the same result you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

cols_template= ["A", "B", "C"]

def concat_missingvals(df):
    out = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, len(df)), columns=cols_template)],
                    ignore_index=True).dropna(how="all")
    return out

df = (
        pd.read_excel("testData.xlsx",
                      usecols=["Source", "Number"])
            .drop_duplicates()
            .assign(idx= lambda x: x.groupby("Source").cumcount())
            .pivot(index="Source", columns="idx")
            .transpose()
            .reset_index(drop=True)
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
            .pipe(concat_missingvals)
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

      A     B     C
0  10.1  10.2  10.3
1  10.4  10.5  10.6
```

You can then use [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) to store the result dataframe in an new Excel file.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("testData_Retouche.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="Result")
    col_idx = df.columns.get_loc('A') #Put the column name here
    writer.sheets['Result'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, 10) #10 is the column width
```

##### # Input used (testData.xlsx) :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a lot cleaner than what I was trying to accomplish. Lets say I have source in Column B, and Number in Column K with other data in between. How would I only target column K? The code as is will also copy over data in the other columns.

Comment: In this case, you can use `usecols` parameter of the function `pd.read_excel` to use the columns `Source` and `Number` regardless of their positions in the Excel sheet. I updated my answer, check it out!

Comment: thanks so much for the help. It worked and I edited the code so that it could iterate through multiple sheets as well as use argparse. One concern though is that, say for example in testData, if is no number associated with source "C", the output doesn't have a column with header "C". Is there a workaround so that the output retains column header "C"?

Comment: Yes, you can make this out by for example creating an empty dataframe with your template columns and then use `pd.concat`. Answer updated.

Comment: Lastly, if I'm trying to set a column width, where would I place `.set_column` ?

Comment: FWIW even though this is the correct approach, for a dataset this small there will be no noticeable difference in performance. And there is **always** an overhead in going between Pandas and Excel.

Comment: @Wolk, you can place it inside a context manager of `pandas.ExcelWriter`. Look at the update I made to my answer.

Comment: @CharlieClark, you're absolutely right. Maybe the real dataset of the OP is much bigger than the minimal reproducible example shown in the image.

Comment: Possibly, but it's also important not to push the idea of performance, where it may not matter or not happen. TBH I think a "pure" openpyxl solution here would be faster.